# How to make a Push Notification Settings page in Flutter?

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make a push-notification-settings page in my Flutter app. The page should allow the user to configure which push notification he/she wants to receive. For example one wants to receive a notification for a friend request, but doesn't want to be notified when another user accepts a friend request. I wasn't able to find anything related to such a feature, although I think this is a common feature that almost every app provides.

I have already implemented the sending of push notifications for several events in my Node.js (Express.js) backend with Firebase. The push notification is being received using the [Firebase cloud messaging plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) for Flutter.

I want to implement it using basic toggles or checkboxes like this (example from the app [Trello](https://trello.com/)):
[image: Trello-push-notification-settings-page]

Does anyone know how to do that or where I can retrieve information regarding this topic?

Comment: Were you able to do this? Please share what you where able to do.Thanks

Comment: That was a long time ago. But sadly I can't say that I was able to achieve anything close to the wanted features :,)